# Not able to access my Flask server through ingress

Tags: flask, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am new to the concepts of Flask and k8s and trying to implement a very simple Flask server via k8s for getting familiar with the concept.
Am able to access it via NodePort. But after adding ingress service and tweaking my host file in windows machine. When I tried to access the host URL, which I added in ingress-srv.yaml, I am getting a 404 error.

Here is the project Github link: https://github.com/bijay-ps/flask-poc

can someone help me out??

Comment: Actually your setup is working fine: `$ curl flask.com/bye` gives me `Bye World!`. I just downloaded your files and applied it, no changes where made. How did you setup your environment? Is it on Cloud? Private? Which ingress controller are you using?

Comment: @mWatney the setup is local right now. I am planning to host this on Azure and check. See my comment below, it is working on my personal computer but not on my office laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to describe which k8s you are using. (ex. minikube, gcp, azure etc) And version of client and server

```
$ kubectl version                 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T12:36:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17+", GitVersion:"v1.17.5-gke.6", GitCommit:"de3e4dcd39464bc1601edd66681e663bff1fe530", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-05-12T16:10:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

2. Make sure you install [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#contents). There's no default(pre-installed) ingress.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-0.32.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

3. Your yaml configs looks ok.

Comment: It's a coincidence that your answer is very similar to my comment?

Comment: sorry I didn't provide these details. Here is my k8s version:

C:\Users\bijay>kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.2", GitCommit:"52c56ce7a8272c798dbc29846288d7cd9fbae032", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-04-16T11:56:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.6-beta.0", GitCommit:"e7f962ba86f4ce7033828210ca3556393c377bcc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-15T08:18:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: ok, I just tried to replicate the issue on my personal computer and it worked. When I posted the question I was trying on my office laptop and it didn't work. I guess it is some kind of access issue probably for my office laptop, will check it out.